# Understanding java executor service shutdown and awaitTermination

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

need to clarify following behaviour.

I have a java app with `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService` as follows,

```
       for (int i = 0; i < thread_count; i++) {
            Runnable worker = new MyThread(batchSize);
            executor.execute(worker);
        }

        executor.shutdown();
        executor.awaitTermination(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        System.out.println("All threads are finished");
```

In above code I have 5 threads and those are finished in 10 minutes and it will execute `System.out.println("All threads are finished")`, even-though `executor.awaitTermination(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)` has 15 minutes wait time.

But when I remove `executor.shutdown()` the program will wait 15 minutes which is specified in `executor.awaitTermination(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)` statement, before executing next line.

Can any one explain this behaviour ? Why without shutdown command will wait specified amount of time evengthough all the threads are finished ?

Comment: Please always read and try to understand JavaDoc for all methods you are using.

Comment: The "termination" in awaitTermination refers to the termination of the thread pool, not the termination of the tasks, because this was designed primarily with a scenario in mind where new tasks can come in all the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Javadoc for [ExecutorService.awaitTermination](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) says:

> **Blocks until all tasks have completed execution after a shutdown request, or the timeout occurs**, or the current thread is
>   interrupted, **whichever happens first**.

So when you call shutdown(): your threads are finished in 10 minutes. Then awaitTermination returns immediately (without waiting for 15 minutes to pass).

But if you remove the call to shutdown(), there's no shutdown request, so awaitTermination does not return until the timeout passes (15 minutes)

Answer (score 1):

The [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) will immedietly start all tasks that are handed over to him.

[ExecutorService#shutdown](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown--) will cause the `ExecutorService`to stop accepting new tasks and finish the work (start all previous supplied tasks that aren't started till now).

The arguments for [ExecutorService#awaitTermination](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) are the timeout, the amount of time this call will block before it forcefully returns.

In your scenario without calling `shutdown()` your call to `awaitTermination()` will block for the full amount of supplied time, because the `Executor` itself will wait for new work for ever.

Answer (score 0):

The Javadoc for [`ExecutorService.awaitTermination`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) method states:

> Blocks until all tasks have completed execution after a shutdown
>   request, or the timeout occurs, or the current thread is interrupted,
>   whichever happens first.